# What is the meaning or interpretation of this ES6 function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The title is not good and I'll edit it as soon as I find out a name for this.

I've been learning Redux and it's the first place I've seen this kind of function.

```
export default connect(null, actionCreators)(TodoApp)
```

I can't get my head around, clearly "null" and "actionCreators" are params passed to the connect function, but what is "(TodoApp)" doing?

Comment: `connect(null, actionCreators)` returns an anonymous function to which `TodoApp` is passed to.

Comment: Fantastic, if you add it as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript supports first class functions this is, they can be passed around like normal data. So `connect(null, actionCreators)` returns an anonymous function to which `TodoApp` is passed to.

A simple understandable example would be:

```html
var obj = {
  name: "Test",
  age: 10
}

var f = () => {
  // Do whatever f function should do
  
  // Return an anonymous function that takes in an object as parameter
  return (obj) => {
    
    // Do whatever we want to to with the object
    console.log(obj.name)
  }
}

// These two methods are equivalent
  // 1.- 
  f()(obj);

  // 2.-
  var f2 = f();
  f2(obj);
```

Comment: @Borjante You've explained it yourself somehow :D

Comment: Well, tanks to your initial comment I have done some tests to make sure I get the idea behind correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
connect(null, actionCreators)(TodoApp);
```

is as good as :

```
var fun = connect(null, actionCreators);
fun(TodoApp);
```

Its something like this :

```js
function connect(val1,val2){
  console.log(val1,val2);
  return function(val3){
    console.log(val3);  
  }
}

var actionCreators = "X";
var TodoApp = "Some Object";

connect(null, actionCreators)(TodoApp);
```

As you can see, `connect` takes two inputs,

Returns an anonymous method, which takes one input.